# How to manipulate isolated scope input variables?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to manipulate the data sent to my directive, ie. I have a myUser directive that displays the user name and is used like this:

```
<my-user id="25" name="John Doe"></my-user>
```

I would like it to convert to:

```
<a ng-click="navTo('/user/25')">John&nbsp;Doe</a>
```

So I would like to replace any spaces with `&nbsp;` and set the new location according to the user's id. Here is my directive definition:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myUser', function ($location, $log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            name: '@'
        },
        template: '<a ng-click="navTo(\'/users/\' + {{id}})">{{name}}</a>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.name.replace(' ', '&nbsp;');
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, fn) {
            scope.name.replace(' ', '&nbsp;');

            scope.navTo = function (route) {
                $log.info('Navigating to ' + route);
                $location.path(route);
            };

        }
    };
});
```

However, the replace does not take place. I assume both the controller and link functions are executed after the template has been rendered.

Also, the navTo function returns the following error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'id' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 21 of the expression [navTo('/users/' + {{id}})] starting at [id}})].
```

Any ideas on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the `{{}}` around `id`.

Comment: it we dont have {{}} value will not be interpolated and it will give string 'id' instead of value 25

Comment: @AnthonyChu - great, it works without the {{}}. Any ideas why the replace does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your template with below line and it should work

```
template: '<a ng-click=\'navTo("/users/{{id}}")\'>{{name}}</a>',
```

Comment: Thanks! I played around with it some more, and this version worked for me: `template: '<a ng-click=\'navTo("/neighbor/" + id)\'>{{name}}</a>',`

Comment: This doesn't work. Outputs `Navigating to /users/{{id}}` (ng-click doesn't support interpolation)... http://jsfiddle.net/9vFrA/

Answer (score 0):

`ng-click` takes an expression and doesn't need interpolation, so you don't need to use `{{}}`. You can just remove them, like this...

```
template: '<a ng-click="navTo(\'/users/\' + id)">{{name}}</a>'
```

[Live Demo - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T5W2H/)